# How can you give ApplicationPoolIdentity permissions to write to the Application Event Log?

Tags: iis, permissions, azure-web-app-service, event-log

How can you give `ApplicationPoolIdentity` permissions to write to the Application Event Log?

I've read about adding a user to the permissions for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` but I can't find the user `ApplicationPoolIdentity`

And how can I have this as part of the deployment for a web site? ... specifically to Azure Web App Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the registry of an instance in App Service as the sandbox in Azure App Service doesn't allow you to modify registry. More details [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#general-sandbox-restrictions)

As long as you are not creating a new Event Source, your application logging will continue to work and the events will be written to EventLog.xml (which is a lightweight event log file). You can read more details about this in https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#access-to-event-log.

You can access the eventlog.xml file directly from KUDU under D:\HOME\LOGFILES folder, or from support portal or by using a website extension which I wrote some time back. More details on this in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/puneetgupta/2014/09/24/azure-website-siteextension-to-view-eventlogs/